# How do I validate my drop down list with javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to validate my drop down list to current javascript function.

Javascript

```
function theteam() {
    document.add_team_frm.action = "team.php";
    document.add_team_frm.submit();
}
```

HTML

```
<form name="add_team_frm" action="team.php" method="post">
<select name="team_name[]">
<option value="0">Select Team</option>
<option value="1">Team A</option>
<option value="2">Team B</option>
<option value="3">Team C</option>
</select>
<a href="javascript:theteam()">Submit Team</a>
</form>
```

I use link as submit button. How do I add a a validation on `name="team_name[]"` to the `theteam()` if `value = 0`

Let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
function theteam(){

   //check select
   if(document.getElementById('selectID').value == 'whatever'){
        document.forms['add_team_frm'].submit();
   }
   else { /*select check failed*/ }

}
```

Comment: Worth noting you'll need to amend your HTML above to include an id='selectID' along with the name in your select for this to work...